# Throttling Jenkins shared library clones on the master

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, throttling

I'm not sure if I summarized this well in the title, so suggestions are welcome.

**Jenkins Configuration:**

- A Jenkins linux master with 0 executors.
- Many different agents/agent executors.
- Many declarative pipeline jobs with mostly scripted stages.
- The declarative pipeline specifies `agent { label "some-label" }`
- Many trusted shared libraries (those configured in the main Jenkins configuration) are loaded using git as the VCS.
- Most of those shared libraries above are intentionally loaded implicitly rather than explicitly.

**Assumption:**
When shared libraries are loaded implicitly, they are always cloned on the master and the scripts are loaded into memory prior to executing the actual pipeline code.

**Problem:**
For each pipeline that runs, X number of trusted shared libraries are cloned on the master before any pipeline code can be serialized and run on an agent.
There is no way that I'm aware that you can tell Jenkins to only run N number of clones on the master at once.  The end result is that when a lot of pipelines run at the same time, the number of git clones running on the master at the same time is significant, which overwhelms either the Jenkins server or the git server and causes the builds to fail (either due to a timeout or another related cause).

**Workaround (Sort of)**
Load as few trusted shared libraries implicitly and then have them loaded explicitly while wrapped in `lock ... { }` from the [Lockable Resources Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin) to throttle the number of git clones.
This doesn't really solve the need though, as there's specific reasons you would need to use implicit loading vs explicit.

Hopefully I'm missing something obvious :)

Comment: I believe you are right about not being able to change Jenkins' behavior itself (now). I think most answers to this would be opinion, but I'll brainstorm a few ideas. * Do something at the network level by limiting connections and bandwidth. * Merge some of libraries together since they are implicitly loaded anyways. * Periodically sync repositories from your VCS to the Jenkins master, and have the global library configuration point at those local file resources. * Make sure VCS is properly sized and tuned, possibly use a read-replica. Those are just a few things to think about, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

of course my suggestion is **opinionated**.

the following item has caused my eyebrows raise:

> Many trusted shared libraries (those configured in the main Jenkins configuration) are loaded using git as the VCS.

Given this ticket is open with very few comments/votes:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48210,

Jenkins community does not feel it compelling to many.

I think the documentation on jenkins website about the libraries,
has some hidden assumptions:

1. **SHARED** library makes sense only if its code is used in multiple jobs, i.e. reducing code duplication. you may abuse the idea by wrapping each job's code into  pseudo-"shared" library code, ... it's an abuse of terminology, IMHO
2. you cannot push or pull through the network more than it can give/take ;)

So what aRe the practical AIs you could deduce:

1. UPGRADE H/W: the cheapest solution (considering developer hourly rate vs. hardware cost) is to buy better NICs or spin up beefier VMs and allocate more throughput for them
2. I would revisit how you are structuring your shared libraries. leave shared code in 1 happy library with several classes, and this shall reduce number of git traffic to 1 per each build.

Also, some more info about what speed of links you have between your CI network and git server, and how many jobs are there running [O(?)] in parallel would be also nice to know.

Please tell me how have you resolved you issues.
(sounds very interesting, I would love to learn more!)